# Squashing migrations speeded up tests - and not just the database setup part

Tags: django, testing

I have been struggling with slow tests - really slow tests. I thought that was probably due to inefficient data setup within my tests. I did some 'before' time measurements and then, for unrelated reasons, squashed all my migrations. Then I ran my tests again. I did not change any of the test code - only the migrations - but the tests are dramatically faster. I had expected some improvement in the database setup number reported with `--timing` but I had not expected much change in the speed with which the tests themselves run. Can anyone offer an explanation for this?

### Before

| Method | DB setup | DB teardown | Running Test | Total elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MySQL | 124.2s | 3.6s | 794.5s | 925.0s |
| MySQL keepdb 1 | 123.8s | 0s | 742.5s | 869.2s |
| MySQL keepdb 2 | 4.3s | 0s | 742.2s | 759.1s |
| SQLite run 1 | 4.9s | 0s | 886.7s | 896.3s |
| SQLite run 2 | 4.3s | 0s | 778.1s | 785.2s |

### After squashing migration

| Method | DB setup | DB teardown | Running Test | Total elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MySQL | 107.8s | 6.5s | 200.0s | 319.5s |
| MySQL | 109.3s | 6.9s | 205.3s | 326.4s |
| SQLite run 1 | 34.3s | 0s | 128.2s | 166.9s |
| SQLite run 2 | 1.5s | 0s | 124.6s | 130.3s |

Answer (score 1):

Update. I did some more testing of my assumptions - checking out code from right before the migration squashing (and from the time period where I had taken the original data). In both cases I am now seeing the older code running tests in a more reasonable time frame - with the main differences being in the database setup times. My only explanation is that I must have had something else running on my laptop the day I took the original dismal timings.

Right before the squash

| Method | DB setup | DB teardown | Running Test | Total elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MySQL | 191.2s | 8.1s | 207.4s | 415.5s |

Code from same period as the "before" measurements in my question

| Method | DB setup | DB teardown | Running Test | Total elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MySQL | 183.8s | 6.5s | 190.5s | 386.4s |